# how can pass the Switch case condition with IF Statement

Tags: java

Please suggest how can pass the the Switch case Condition with IF Statement

baseclass.java

```
class Baseclass {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public void GetDriver(int browserId) {
        {
            switch (browserId) {
            case 1:
                // For Firefox Driver
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;

            case 2:
                // For Chrome Driver
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;

            case 3:
                // For IE Driver
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                        "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

another class i have inherit the base class and set the condition

```
public class AdminRenewals extends Baseclass {

@BeforeTest
    public final void Startup() {
        Baseclass ed = new Baseclass();
        ed.GetDriver(3);
}
}
```

from the AdminRenewals class how can we check the switch case condition with another method

sonething like

```
if(GetDriver==2)
            {
            if (!name1.equals("")) {
                name1 = new StringBuffer(name1).insert(name1.length() - 1, " ")
                        .toString();

if(GetDriver==3) 
            {
            if (!name1.equals("")) {
                name1 = new StringBuffer(name1).insert(name1.length() - 1, "test ")
                        .toString();
```

Expected:
if i use the chrome driver its should be execute that particular if condition (based on switch case)

Comment: You have a serious design flaw. Why you are creating instance of BaseClass in child?

Comment: What do you mean by "IF loop"?  There's no such thing, so it's not clear what you mean.  Also, you might get better answers if you ask someone who speaks good English to help you formulate the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if(Baseclass.driver instanceof FirefoxDriver)
{
    ...
}
if(Baseclass.driver instanceof ChromeDriver)
{
    ...
}
```

etc.

Using `instanceof`, you can determine which type of `WebDriver` was created and assigned to `driver`.

[Learn more about instanceof here!](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm)

(Your question wasn't very clear, so I believe this is what you were asking, but if it isn't then comment below with more info and I will update my answer)